# Old CoreData model being loaded onto device, correct one is on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I just updated to Xcode 5.1, and now when I run my app on a device (debug or ad hoc distro), it's using a very old version of my CoreData model. When I run the app on my simulator, it uses the most recent, correct, version of my model.  The issue occurs on iPads running 7.0.x and 7.1, I don't have a 6.x to test with.

The problem shows up with an unrecognizedSelector message in the console:
**-[SiteCD setHasSynced:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147237c0**

And then the app just stops responding, and it doesn't proceed to the next line of code.

I grabbed the application files from the device and inspected the sqlite file that was on the device.  It is, indeed, missing the **hasSynced** property from the model. 
CREATE TABLE ZSITECD ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZSITEID INTEGER, ZADDRESS1 VARCHAR, ZADDRESS2 VARCHAR, ZADDRESS3 VARCHAR, ZFULLNAME VARCHAR, ZSITEDESCRIPTION VARCHAR );

Here is the model that is running on my simulator:
CREATE TABLE ZSITECD ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, **ZHASSYNCED INTEGER**, ZSITEID INTEGER, ZADDRESS1 VARCHAR, ZADDRESS2 VARCHAR, ZADDRESS3 VARCHAR, ZFULLNAME VARCHAR, ZSITEDESCRIPTION VARCHAR );

I've verified that my active model version is set correctly and I've googled, stack overflow-ed, and searched the Apple forums.  I'm at a complete loss and I would appreciate any advice from the community that you have.

Is there a way to find out what version of the model the app is using at runtime?
I didn't receive the build warning to update the project settings for this project, is there a way to trigger that message manually?
I've tried cleaning/rebuilding.
The app on my device was running previously with my most recent model version (an app built with Xcode 5.0.x) prior to installing this recent app build over it (built with Xcode 5.1).

**Update** I reinstalled Xcode 5.0.2 and built the same app using it and ran it on my device.  The model is back to the right one, the most recent.  Then I re-built the app using Xcode 5.1 and the **old/incorrect** model still loaded.  I am going to try some more of Marcus's suggestions tonight.

**Update Again** I pulled up the model property files from the application bundles and something very curious happened.  The Xcode 5.1 build is *missing the version key*.  The first screenshot is the 5.0.2 build, and the second screenshot is the 5.1 build.  So now I see what is wrong, but I still have no idea how that is happening on identical code.

[image: correct version properties (5.0.2)]
[image: missing version key (5.1)]

Answer (score 1):

At runtime you can inspect the `NSManagedObjectModel` to see what the hashes are for the entities.  You can compare those against the same app running on the simulator.

It sounds as if you have a build issue on the device(s).  If you had a pre-versioning model (with just a .mom) and now have a versioned model (.momd folder with .mom files inside) it can cause confusion to Core Data.

Some solutions:

1. Specify the file name when you create your `NSManagedObjectModel` instance instead of just grabbing all models.
2. Remove the app from the device and install fresh to insure you don't have old files in there.
3. Manually inspect the bundle being pushed and see if there are multiple copies of your model file.

### Update

1. Instead of using `-mergedModelFromBundles:nil` I am suggesting that you change it to use `-initWithContentsOfURL:` so that you can eliminate the possibility that there is an older model file somewhere in the application structure.
2. If a removal and a reinstall doesn't clear it then you may have an old file being compiled into your project incorrectly.  Another consideration is how you are building your Core Data stack.  Are you checking for all of the possible errors and reporting them properly so that you can see if there is a failure in the stack creation?  Every `error:` should have a pointer passed into it and the response from the method should be checked for an error condition.  Many of the errors in Core Data can be silent if you don't check for them.
3. I am not suggesting check the models, but actually open up the application **bundle** and check it to see if there are any files in there.  It is possible in your build to compile a `.mom` outside of the versioned directory which can then cause an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My model has been versioned for a few years at this point (momd).  1) this is what I've always used for the managed object model: managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

Comment: 2) I did remove the app and start fresh but it gave the same result of using the wrong model.  Plus this won't work for my production application.

Comment: 3) I inspected the models being sent to the simulator and device, and they appear to be identical except that the simulator has an additional file Model 15.omo and the device doesn't.  I've never noticed a .omo file before, so I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  My item 3 was opening the application bundle and seeing the model files.  They both had one model folder in them with all of the same .mom files.  The .omo was the only difference.  An additional update, I re-installed Xcode 5.0.2 and when I build with that version, the correct model is loaded onto the device.  I am going to try your Update suggestions now, thank you again!

Comment: Hi Marcus, I just added some screenshots to my description.  It's very strange to see that the property for the Current model version is missing completely from my Xcode 5.1 builds.  I'm going to install Xcode 5.1.1 and see if the same bug presents itself still.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Xcode 5.1.1 and the issue is mysteriously gone.  I never was able to get to a root cause or solution, I'm just happy that now it's no longer a problem.  Thanks to Marcus for all of his help, I wish I had a better answer and I hope it never pops up again.

Comment: That is wild.  Must have been an issue in Xcode then.  Great to hear it got resolved.